# How do i convert this SQL to Entity Framework LINQ query

Tags: sql, .net, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

Can someone help me convert this SQL Query to EntityFramework LINQ? [image: Entity schema]

```
DECLARE @UserId varchar(50) = '123'
SELECT
   TL.TrackId, 
   COUNT(*) AS LikeCount,
   (SELECT IIF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'true','false') FROM UserTrackLikes WHERE
    UserId = @UserId AND TrackId = TL.TrackId) AS IsLiked
FROM TrackList AS TL
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTrackLikes AS UTL 
ON UTL.TrackId = TL.TrackId
GROUP BY TL.TrackId
```

Comment: You can still use sql in entity framework 6 using the `DbSet.SqlQuery` method.

Comment: @jeuxjeux20 yes, but i want to know how to convert this to linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query syntax:

```
int userId = 123;
var result = (from trackList in context.TrackLists
              select new 
              {
                 trackList.TrackId,
                 LikeCount = trackList.Likes.Count(),
                 IsLiked = trackList.Likes.Any(x => x.UserId == userId)
              }).ToList();
```

Assuming that here, `Likes` is a collection of `UserTrackLike`, declared like this:

```
public ICollection<UserTrackLike> Likes { get; set; }
```